# When scrolling up in listview, first item keeps re-render

Tags: dart, flutter

I'm experiencing an annoying thing, where the first item in my listview keeps re-render, when scrolling up. Even if I'm at the top.

only way i noticed this, was because I have a widget, that on load, fetches an url, and get the meta title, description and image, and displaying it in a nice card.

My listviews are fairly simple:

```
ListView.builder(
  physics: AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics(),
  controller: _scrollController,
  itemCount: model.posts.posts.length,
  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
     // Items goes here
  });
```

How do I stop it from happening?

The widget that keeps re-rendering, is a stateless widget that imports a ScopedModel model, that fetches some data from the internet, and scraped for meta data, and then updated the model.

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  UrlEmbedModel _model = new UrlEmbedModel(); // <-- the ScopedModel

  _model.fetchHtml(url); // <-- the url param comes from the constuctor

  // Rest of the widget
}
```

Here is the code that fetches content from the net.

```
void fetchHtml(url) {
  http.get(url).then((response) {
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      // If server returns an OK response, parse the JSON
      var document = parse(response.body);

      var list = document.getElementsByTagName('meta');

      for (var item in list) {

        if (item.attributes['property'] == "og:title") {
          _title = item.attributes['content'];
        }

        if (item.attributes['property'] == "og:description") {
          _description = item.attributes['content'];
        }

        if (item.attributes['property'] == "og:image") {
          _imageUrl = item.attributes['content'];
        }

        notifyListeners();
      }
    } else {
      // If that response was not OK, throw an error.
      throw Exception('Failed to load post');
    }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the culprit.

The issue wasn't the listview, it was the RefreshIndicator that I used.

As soon I removed it, the issue went away.

This seems to be a bug with Widget.

Comment: Upon further inspection, it was the library ScopedModel that was the issue.

Answer (score 1):

The code you wrote, seems OK, but what about the function that makes the request? Can you show it?

If it's a Future function, it'll only make a request once and then finish it, it's not like a stream function that will be always listening to an event.

**EDIT**

First of all, if this functions makes a request, then, the type of the functions must be `Future`, void type if don't return anything, after that, add the `async` call. You could change the .then method to an await method, it'll suit you better.

```
Future<void> fetchHtml(url) async {

 final Response response = await get(url);

 final dynamic documents = json.decode(response.body); //import 'dart:convert';

  print(documents); // print to see what you get than, pass it to the variables you want the data

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      //in here
    }

}
```

I can see a feel things in the fetch request, I'd be glad if you answer it:

1. Why you're not deserializing the json you receiving?

   `var documents = json.decode(response.body)`
2. You could print the documents variable after deserializing it and atribute it to the widgets you want

The way you're doing it it's not wrong, but could improve it.

Comment: Well, the method doesn't need to return anything, as it automatically updates the scoped model.

And second, I'm not fetching json, I'm fetching the html response, and parsing it.